# How do you make a one time "I agree" activity screen for users on your app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can you help me figure out how to make it so my app has users check mark an I agree box before my app goes to the main menu? I need it to only show this screen the very first time the user uses the app. I am new to android studio so any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to accomplish this. try doing something like:

```
final String PREF_NAME = "MyPref";

// getting saved preferences
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);

if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {
    //the app is being launched for first time, do something        
    Log.d("Comments", "First time");

             // first time task
             runUserAgreements();

    // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
    settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).commit(); 
}
```

Then declare a function named `runUserAgreements()` and run an activity or dialog showing User Agreements and stuff.

### EDIT:

I suggest to put above code in a class extending `Application`
 to check firstrun generally not in the default activity:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // CODE HERE

    }
}
```

and **DO NOT** forget to call the class in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name=".MyApp"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             .
             .
             ...>
....
</application>
```

Comment: The answer by Sdghasemi is excellent. I've used it too. BTW, I also store the time of last "I agree" and pop it up again every a week or so - just to be sure, for liability mitigation reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google's [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main) project example, specifically this Activity: [Welcome Activity](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/WelcomeActivity.java). IMHO it has a pretty good UI design too.